# Splitting a string into an array of strings in C

Tags: c, string, split, segmentation-fault

This problem frustrates me; I've solved it before but I can't remember exactly how anymore and it's come up time and again!

You're given a string, like a list of fruit, separated by commas. You want to split the string into an array of strings at the comma. I can't figure out why I keep getting segmentation faults! Here's my code:

```
char** split(char *);
int count_words(char *);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  char *my_list = "Apple, banana, cherry, dragonfruit, elderberry";
  char **split_list = split(my_list);

  /*int i = 0;
  while(split_list[i] != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", split_list[i]);
    i++;
    }*/

  return 0;
}

char** split(char *str) {
  int num_words = count_words(str);
  char **my_words = malloc((num_words + 1) * sizeof(char*));

  const char delim[2] = ",";
  char *token;
  token = strtok(str, delim);

  for(int i = 0; i < num_words; i++) {
    my_words[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(token));
    strcpy(my_words[i], token);

    token = strtok(NULL, delim);
  }

  my_words[i] = NULL;

  return my_words;
}

int count_words(char *str) {
  int cnt = 0;
  while(*str != '\0') {
    if(*str == ',') cnt++;
    str++;
  }

  return ++cnt;
}
```

Comment: Aren't you starting to copy from `token` one word too late? It will point to right *after* the first comma.

Comment: my_words[i] = NULL; - does this compile at all? if so, what's the value of i at this point?

Comment: Also, `strtok()` writes to the string it's given, and you passing it a string constant.

Comment: You are trying to split a read-only string literal.

Comment: Splitting a read-only string literal is a no-no.

Comment: Yeah that was unfortunately my fault; posted the question before I commented that out. It would not compile at all. I originally had a while loop where I declared i outside of the loop so it worked. But then I switched to a for loop and forgot to comment that line out. Disregard it!

Comment: Bingo n.m and Igor! That was the problem. I forgot strtok writes to the string. Using a string literal would cause that seg fault, right on!

Comment: One suggestion, format your code more carefully, you will be happy in the future. :)

Answer (score 2):

My goodness, I had a huge brainfart...

The answer is simply that the string I was using was a constant with read-only access. 
Declaring a string like this: `char *myStr = "Hello World"` is read-only! You can't write into it.

Solution code:

```
char** split(char *);
int count_words(char *);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    const char *string = "Apple, banana, cherry, dragonfruit, elderberry";
char *my_list = malloc(1 + strlen(string)); //random number
strcpy(my_list, string);
char **split_list = split(my_list);

int i = 0;
while(split_list[i] != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", split_list[i]);
    free(split_list[i]);
    i++;
}
free(split_list);
free(my_list);

return 0;
}

char** split(char *str) {
int num_words = count_words(str);
char **my_words = malloc((1 + num_words) * sizeof(char*));
const char delim[2] = ",";
char *token;
token = strtok(str, delim);

int i = 0;
while(token != NULL) {
    my_words[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (1 + strlen(token)));
    strcpy(my_words[i], token);

    token = strtok(NULL, delim);
    i++;
}
my_words[i] = NULL;

return my_words;
}

int count_words(char *str) {
int cnt = 0;

while(*str != '\0')
{
    if(*str == ',')
        cnt++;
    str++;
}

return ++cnt;
}
```

Comment: You have memory leaks for all malloc calls, you dont allocate space for the null termination byte in `my_words[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(token));`. And your initial copy of the string is not the best idea. But your anser is still correct.

Comment: Yeah I probably posted this question way too early; I just realized I could have done: char my_list[] = "Apple, Banana...etc";